# No api proxy found for service "taskqueue"

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

When I'm trying to `python manage.py changepassword` command I get this errror:

```
AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "taskqueue"
```

Here's what I have in my `PYTHONPATH`:

```
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
lib/:/usr/local/google_appengine
```

And my `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` points to the settings file that I use for GAE:

```
$ echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
settings.dev
```

There's some package for `taskqueue` in appengine api folder:

```
/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/taskqueue$ ls
__init__.py  __init__.pyc  taskqueue.py  taskqueue.pyc  taskqueue_service_pb.py  taskqueue_service_pb.pyc  taskqueue_stub.py  taskqueue_stub.pyc
```

What could I miss here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume `manage.py` is executing sdk methods without starting a local `dev_appserver`. `dev_appserver.py` sets up stubs to emulate the services available once your application is deployed. When you are executing code locally and outside of the running app server, you will need to initialize those stubs yourself.

The app engine docs have a section on testing that tells you [how to initialize those stubs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting?hl=en#Python_Writing_task_queue_tests). It isn't the exact solution to your issue, but it can point you to the stubs you need to set up.

```
import unittest

from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
from google.appengine.ext import deferred
from google.appengine.ext import testbed


class TaskQueueTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
        self.testbed.activate()

        # root_path must be set the the location of queue.yaml.
        # Otherwise, only the 'default' queue will be available.
        self.testbed.init_taskqueue_stub(root_path='tests/resources')
        self.taskqueue_stub = self.testbed.get_stub(
            testbed.TASKQUEUE_SERVICE_NAME)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.testbed.deactivate()

    def testTaskAddedToQueue(self):
        taskqueue.Task(name='my_task', url='/url/of/my/task/').add()
        tasks = self.taskqueue_stub.get_filtered_tasks()
        assert len(tasks) == 1
        assert tasks[0].name == 'my_task'
```

Comment: The above solution is for a test. I'm trying to use taskqueue in a middleware and I'm stuck with this error. `from google.appengine.api import apiproxy_stub_map

apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy = apiproxy_stub_map.GetDefaultAPIProxy()` tried this in a settings.py didn't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Pannu if you have a question on how to do something, I suggest you create a new question instead of commenting on this answer. App Engine changes rapidly and what was relevant in 2015 is no longer relevant now.

Comment: how to implement this in django 4.1 and python 3.8 i am getting the same error

Comment: @JaskaranSingh if you have a question on how to do something, I suggest you create a new question instead of commenting on this answer. App Engine changes rapidly and what was relevant in 2015 is no longer relevant now.